# Maximum Entropy Distribution with Constraint

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I want to find the solution for the maximum entropy distribution with a cost constraint. The specific problem setup is as follows:

1. Let $\bf{x}$ be a probability distribution.
2. Let $\bf{c}$ be the cost vector associated with the distribution.
3. Let $m$ be the maximum allowable cost of the distribution. In other words, $\textbf{c}^\top\textbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i \le m$.
4. I want to maximize the entropy of $\bf{x}$ subject to this constraint. Mathematically, this is equivalent to minimizing, $\textbf{x}^\top \log(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i)$.

I'm struggling to calculate the analytic solution using Lagrangian duality. I'm also unable to implement a numeric solution in Python. Solutions to either of these approaches would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up the Lagrangian,
\begin{align*}
L = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \log(x_i) + \lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i x_i - m\right) + \mu\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i - 1\right)
\end{align*}
Computing the stationary points,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = \log(x_i) + 1 + \lambda c_i + \mu\overset{\text{set}}{=} 0 \implies x_i = e^{-1 - \lambda c_i - \mu}
\end{align*}
This stationary point is already $\ge 0$, so we just need to ensure $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_ix_i = m$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1$. Using the second constraint, we can solve for $\mu$
\begin{align*}
\mu = \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-1 - \lambda c_i}\right)
\end{align*}
Plugging this into the first constraint, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c_i - m)e^{-1 - \lambda c_i} = 0
\end{align*}
At this point, you may use numerical methods like Newton-Raphson to find $\lambda$. As a sanity check, letting $c_i = m$ does result in $x_i = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Does this approach take into account that the solution needs to be a probability distribution (additional constraints: $x_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$)? I just tried it out and got a weird solution on a sample problem where $m=1$, $n=7$ and $\textbf{c}=[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]^\top$. If you can show what the solution is in this case, I can go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: Edited, apologies for not realizing earlier. With the above edit, the one-step solution trick no longer works, and you need to iterate through Newton-Raphson, or some other general iterative procedure, directly. Letting $\lambda = 0$ seems like a good starting point.

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought the solution was but wanted to confirm. I'm fine with using numerical methods for $\lambda$. I was having difficulty optimizing $n$ parameters but optimizing one is simple.

Comment: As a side note, if some $c_i=m$, I'm not sure how that leads to $x_i=\frac{1}{n}$. For instance, if all the other $c_j$'s are greater than $m$, then $x_i=1$ and the rest are zero. Did you mean if each $c_i=\frac{m}{n}$ then each $x_i=\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: For $c_i = m$, the equation is always satisfied for any $\lambda$. At the same time, we arrive at $\mu = \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-1-\lambda m}\right)$ and $x_i = e^{-1-\lambda m}/\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-1-\lambda m} = 1/n$.

Comment: Could you explain please why we don’t have a negative sign in our entropy when you plug it into Lagrange?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the Lagrangian"? What is that?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to implement and numerically solve in CVXPY, using the supplied function `entr` .

The entropy maximization example at https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/applications/max_entropy.html?highlight=entropy can be modified for your problem by changing the constraints.